# How to use MySQL in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)?

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How to use mysql in wsl without installing any separate MySQL client for Windows.

Comment: Using the [MySQL Command-Line Tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) from the WSL itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your bash command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have accessed MySQL installed in Windows 10 through WSL:

**1. Create a user with remote access**

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**2. Update mysql.ini**

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
# skip-external-locking
```

**3. Test connection using local IP**

```
>mysql -h192.xxx.xx.xx -P 3306 -unewuser -p
```

Comment: See related articles: https://serverfault.com/q/257513/119666 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/54377052/470749