# How to connect to WSL mysql from Host Windows

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to connect HeidiSql from the host  to my WSL Mysql but I could not get it to connect it

Error "can't connect to Mysql server on '127.0.0.1'"

Tried SSH too but could not connect to the server

[image]

Comment: I finally figured out that I need to upgrade MySQL Workbench from 6 to 8 since WSL 1 had MySQL 8 installed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67963231/470749

Answer (score 15):

By default, MySql only listens on 127.0.0.1. If you are connecting using the IP address returned by `wsl hostname -I` (as mentioned by [Permana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377052/how-to-connect-to-wsl-mysql-from-host-windows#comment121313869_60014486)) then you need to change /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf to listen on all IPs or your specific IP.

Edit your MySql config by typing this in your Ubuntu instance:
`sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Change the line:
`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

To:
`bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

or change `0.0.0.0` to the IP returned by `wsl hostname -I`.

Restart MySql using: `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this did not work. I did change my mysql's bind config to `0.0.0.0`. Also, the IP reported by ifconfig is different from the one reported by `wsl hostname -I`. Connecting to the machine IP given by ifconfig worked though.

EDIT: Nevermind, I used `wsl hostname -i` instead of `-I` (notice the capital I)

Answer (score 13):

I'm also hosting mysql-server on WSL and running MySQL workbench on Windows.

I had to get the IP inside of WSL
[image: ifconfig]

And use this IP in MySQL Workbench
[image]

Comment: For any future readers, you're looking for the `flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>` config

Comment: What I think "9 Guy" means is that `ifconfig`'s output will often show *multiple* IP addresses, and the way to figure out which one to use is to look for the line after the line containing `flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>`.

Comment: another alternative: `wsl hostname -I` to get WSL IP's from cmd.

Answer (score 8):

Since your question is asked before [WSL2 release](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/), I assume you were using WSL1.

### For WSL1

You can access WSL1 MySQL directly from Windows, but you were attempting access in a wrong way.

In the *Network type*, you should choose *MariaDb or MySQL(TCP/IP)* instead of *MySQL (SSH Tunnel)*.

### For WSL2

Check this [WSL github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150). Save @edwindijas's powershell script and execute it by administrator. If you still cannot access MySQL and got `access denied for user ... <you-computer-name>.mshome.net`, you need to allow this user access from this `host`.

For example: let's say root, you need execute this in mysql cli:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%<you-computer-name>.mshome.net' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';`

Or allow root user access WSL2 MySQL from any host:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'' at line 1`

Comment: on Mysql 8 Use CREATE USER instead, followed by the GRANT statement
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377052/how-to-connect-to-wsl-mysql-from-host-windows

Comment: If you are getting the syntax error as mentioned above, try this:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'localhost'`. Once I had done this, Windows Workbench was able to connect as root to my WSL2 MySQL server install

Answer (score 5):

As for me who's also using WSL for making web based application

first make sure mysql is running on WSL like `sudo service mysql start`

then once started, open HeidiSql and simply connect to it, here the example on my part

[image]

make sure the IP address is 127.0.0.1 not any IP, not your IP used to connect on the internet

Comment: this one works for me, unlike the other answer

Comment: @cikatomo Are you using WSL 1 or WSL 2? I can't get 127.0.0.1 (or anything else) to work for me on WSL 1.

Comment: @Ryan I am using WSL1. I haven't use this setup in a while tho. Like few months

Comment: @cikatomo Thanks for your response. I finally figured out that I need to upgrade MySQL Workbench from 6 to 8 since WSL 1 had MySQL 8 installed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67963231/470749

Comment: I was having problems connecting to the WSL MySQL, and this worked, but I needed to disable my windows MySQL80 services and stop it by restating or smt else.

Comment: I have mysql on windows so how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need these steps:

1. open the file "sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf", press `i` to enter the insert mode and use `arrow` keys to go to bottom of the file.
2. add the following line to the end of file `port = 33061`.
3. save the file and exit. press `esc' and then type` :x` to save & exit vim.
4. finally run this command `sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults`.
5. now you can open your client(Navicat) and add a new connection. for the `Host` put `localhost` and for the `port` put `33061`, if you are using `username or password` please provide those too!

Answer (score 0):

**Configure MYSQL**

First of all, make sure your mysql/ mariadb is bound to the interface `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`.
The config file can be edited by `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` while mariadb is `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`.

**Connect through client software**

For your client, simply use `localhost` as your host **don't use an ip address!**

.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am already running a MySQL server on my Windows machine and tried to connect to MySQL which is running from WSL.
This video helped me, please check this :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBsyCk2vZw4

Those who facing the issue, simply change the port in WSL.
I have changed 3306 to 33061 in my.cnf file.

```
[mysqld]
port = 33061
```

And then restarted the service

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Then

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
```

At last, when I connected with the mysql workbench it worked.
Also please make sure, your user is identified by native_password.

[image]