# Cannot connect to MySQL database (running on WSL2) from Windows Desktop Application "MySQL Workbench"

Tags: mysql-workbench, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I set up MySQL on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2 version).  I'm relatively new to MySQL, but I have confirmed the following:

- It is running (`ps ax | grep mysqld` returns a value)
- It is running on default host `127.0.0.1`
- It is running on default port `3306`

To login to the mysql shell, I use the command `sudo mysql -u root -p`.  Without sudo, I am unable to login to the shell.

I assume that this issue has something to do with the host that the MySQL service is running on, but I have no idea how to change that and properly connect.  Below is a screenshot of the connection setup in MySQL Workbench.

[image]

And below is the error that I get when I use the settings shown and my `root` user password.

[image: connect to mysql workbench 2]

[image]

Comment: are you running mysql workbench from the same computer that you can run the command line login or from a different computer?

Comment: It is the same physical device.  MySQL is running on Windows Subsystem for Linux while MySQL Workbench is running on the Windows operating system.

Comment: ah, i think [how to connect to wsl mysql from windows host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377052/how-to-connect-to-wsl-mysql-from-host-windows) may help you.

Comment: Yes, I had seen this post already, but ran the Powershell script and was still not able to connect.

Comment: I think this is the key: allow root user access WSL2 MySQL from any host: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: You shoud post that as an answer and in a day or so, you'll be able to accept it.  It may help someone, and it will be easier if marked as "the answer".

Comment: Are you using mysql 8?

Answer (score 22):

Turns out, this had nothing to do with WSL at all, but rather the authentication method for the MySQL user.

As of MySQL version 5.5.10, users have the ability to use [auth_socket authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html).  In my case, I used the Linux `apt` repository to configure and install MySQL, and this was set as the default authentication method, as shown by the output of the following command:

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

MySQL Workbench does not support this type of authentication, and therefore, you must revert back to the old method of authentication, `mysql_native_password`.

To do this, run the following command while logged in as `root`, or whatever user you are trying to connect to MySQL Workbench with:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password';
```

After doing that, MySQL workbench connects fine.

Comment: THANK YOU for your hint, which led me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67963231/470749! I was so frustrated for many hours.

Answer (score 4):

I have had issues connecting to Mysql running in WSL2 at first but I am now able to connect to the WSL2 MySQL instance via localhost. You just have to make sure that MySQL is listening on all ports which it does by default in MySQL 8.

```
[mysql]
port=3307 # or any port you like
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

[image: MySQL WSL2 connection setup]

[[image: Testing connection from Mysql bench to Mysql running in WSL21]

Comment: Strange in config you have 3307 but in connection 3306 and it connects? Obviously that was the other instance of DB installed on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think to connect from a SQL client (SQLYog, HeidiSQL, etc) to a mariaDB (MySQL) database installed on WSL2 (Windows 10) it is not necessary to change SGDBR config, here is what I did to solve this problem:

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';

This command will set a password to the root user, that's it...
You can now connect to your DB with root/[new_password]

I hope it can help and works for you

More info: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/

Answer (score 0):

Besides creating a user and granting access to localhost and % I had to use the internal IP address for eth0 in WSL. I follow the instructions in [How to connect to WSL mysql from Host Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377052/how-to-connect-to-wsl-mysql-from-host-windows).
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on WSL 1, and unknowingly I have also been using MySQL 8 rather than 5.7.

I tried answers from all across the StackExchange sites for hours, and none of them worked.

Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218981/470749) gave me the idea of checking my MySQL Workbench version. It was 6.

Once I upgraded to MySQL Workbench 8, I was then able to use it to connect to the MySQL 8 server that was running within WSL:

[image]

Note that I'd previously run (in MySQL, in WSL):

```
CREATE USER 'my_local'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxiuyiuyiuyxxx';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'my_local'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else has tried everything above but the workbench still won't connect to the wsl2 database, for me it was the fact that I had mysql installed on windows too (not wsl2) and it's service was running (MYSQL80). Stopping it immediately allowed it to connect to the wsl2 localhost.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30533995)