# Connect MySQL Workbench on WSL MySQL?

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed MySQL on WSL2 with the following

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge *mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
$ sudo apt install -y mysql-server mysql-client
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
...
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                       [ OK ]
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
Setting up mysql-server (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.39) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...

$ sudo service mysql start
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                       No directory, logging in with HOME=/
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//.cache’: Permission denied
-su: 19: /etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh: 
cannot create //.cache/wslu/integration: Directory nonexistent
```

Then I've tried to connect:

```
$ sudo mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)
...    
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

In the meantime I've created the user `laravel` and tried to connect from WSL with `mysql -ularavel -p`.

Eventually I tried to connect from Windows:

[image]

Why is this not working?

Comment: Could it be that `mysql-server` isn't configured to serve network connections? The `mysql-client` when run from the command line, will probably connect via local sockets (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1-in-mysql-connect). What is the output of `sudo mysql -h 127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you need to GRANT access.  I added a new user and GRANTed access.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'newguy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'ratfink';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL ON mysql.* TO 'newguy'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Check the examples down the page [here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)

Then try connecting with user: **newguy** and password: **ratfink** from MySQL Workbench.

Comment: The error is about connectivity to the server, not about permissions being denied.

Comment: Yeah, but without permission you are denied connectivity access.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47524577/470749

Answer (score 1):

It seems previous answers are deprecated.
The below command helped me to solve this problem.

`UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin='mysql_native_password', password=PASSWORD('your_password') WHERE user='your_username' AND host='localhost';`

Then run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Have a great day!