# Attempt on Laravel/MySQLconnection with WSL and XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

First I will explain my setup: I run Laravel in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and I have XAMPP on Windows.
What I'm trying to do is to run MySQL service on XAMPP and connect it with my Laravel project. I have modified my **.env** file setting the root password and I have created the "laravel" database with phpMyAdmin.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

With this setup I tried to run in WSL

```
php artisan migrate
```

But I got this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Then I changed the DB_HOST to localhost, that is a common solution for this, but then I got this other error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Now I have no idea what else to do. I got stucked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `localhost` as hostname?

Comment: Yes, I did. And it didn't work.

Comment: Does this help?  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: WSL doesn't have auto init system. Try starting service manually: sudo service mysql start

Comment: I've tried both solutions but they didn't work

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are running MySQL via XAMPP, under Windows, not in Linux (Ubuntu?).  You should be running MySQL in the WSL2.

See this---
[WSL stack overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60902050/connect-mysql-workbench-on-wsl-mysql/62365738#62365738)

Comment: Yes, that was what I was trying to do. But I didn't know it was an issue with WSL2. Then tried to run MySQL in WSL2 and it worked as you say, but it took me some time to get it working. I guess right now is not possible to do what I was trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging, I found a solution.
First, WSL cannot use localhost to communicate with XAMMP, but it should use `$(hostname).local`. You can test it by typing `ping $(hostname).local` in the WSL terminal: the keyword will be replaced by the host name and IP.

Second point, the app will be connecting from a "foreign" address, not localhost. Therefore, go to your phpMyAdmin interface, select the MySQL user that Flask is using, go to "Login information" and select "Any Host: %" in the "Host" section. I found a guide [here](https://www.hacking-tutorial.com/tips-and-trick/how-to-make-xampp-mysql-database-accessible-by-network/).
Note that now this user can be accessed by your network, so maybe choose a secure password.

More specifically, I had a similar problem with a python Flask app running in WSL, with XAMPP running in Windows. In the app, I had to change my SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI variable to account for the different localhost. The variable should look something like this:

```
export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="mysql+pymysql://sql_user:sql_password@$(hostname).local/YOUR_DATABASE"
```

Edit 2024: I installed WSL 2 in a new machine and this doesn't work anymore. It works with *@$(hostname)* instead of *@$(hostname).local*. There are discussions about this issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8365). I also installed **libnss-mdns** as per [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10077#issuecomment-1736181588), but I am not sure that this is necessary.